# iAd (Apple advertisement framework) integration in ios 7 app

Tags: iad, ios7.1

I am integrating iAd in my app first time. I am successful with this.

My question is, how can I set time between two ads - let's say 10 min. I want to set duration between ads to 10 min.

Is it possible with iAd? or i have to use other ad SDK? I am using ios 7.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry but this is not possible. iAd Banner views are set to a static change time. You can use other ad networks such as adMob which allows you to change ad duration, but be warned they pay out less.